# Prove that $\phi$ is an injective $*$-homomorphism

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

Let $A=C([0,1])$ be an abstract $C^{*}$-algebra. Let $(t_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a dense sequence in $A$, using this, we define $\phi:A\to\mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$ as below: $$\phi(a)=\begin{bmatrix} a(t_1) & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & a(t_2) & 0 &\dots\\
0 & 0 & a(t_3) &\dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{bmatrix}$$

Show that $\phi$ is an injective $*-$homomorphism.

As a newcomer to $C^{*}$-algebra, I don't quite get the idea of solving this problem. Any help please?

Comment: You just have to check the axioms for a *-homomorphism + injectivity (which follows from density). What have you tried and where are you stuck? I can't image showing for example that this map is linear hasn't worked out?

Comment: @QuantumSpace What stuck me is the meaning of the density of $(t_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and of $a(t_1)$. What does it mean for $(t_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ being a dense sequence in $A$? What does $a(t_i)$ represents for $a$ being a continuous function on $[0,1]$?

Comment: As stated, the question makes no sense. You are trying to evaluate elements of $A$ on elements of $A$. But the intent of the question is clear, since $a(t_1)$ is expected to a number and $a$ is a function on $[0,1]$, it should be that $(t_i)$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami As you said I changed the definition of $(t_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ into a dense sequence in $[0,1]$. I have proved the injectivity of $\phi$. Now what confuses me is to prove $\phi(a^{*})=\phi(a)^{*}$. Do you have any hint?

Comment: You need to find what the adjoint is for a diagonal operator, and the adjoint is on $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami After reading a while I found that taking adjoint on $\mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$ is just to take the conjugate transpose of the matrix. Yet I have no idea what the adjoint on $C([0,1])$ is. Do you have any thought?

Comment: It's not a thought, it's the definition. You cannot expect to prove something about a C$^*$-algebra (or any algebraic set, for that matter) if you don't know what the operations are. The algebra $C[0,1]$ is seen as a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra with the adjoint being $f^*(t)=\overline{f(t)}$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami So you mean the set $C([0,1])$ is the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.